# Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key) in php

Tags: php, javascript

Is there an equivalent of this JavaScript code in PHP?

```
var object = {}, key;
Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)
```

Comment: Just a note: The correct JavaScript form for the above is `object.hasOwnProperty(key)` (not `Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)` though it works). There is no `hasOwnProperty` function on `Object` in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), just on `Object.prototype` (and inherited by all objects). Now granted, `Object` inherits from `Object.prototype`, but still, no reason to go round the houses like that, just go straight to the instance in question. I would also *strongly* advise against ever using `object` as a variable name. ;-)

Comment: I was just studying the json_parser and I came across it and I didnt know what it meant :) https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js line 272

Comment: It's a bit of a special use-case. Basically, if there's some possibility that the thing you're testing may not be an object, then you might go the long way 'round like that. But we're talking an edge case. [And I'm not seeing how his `object` could be a non-object either, and I see he's gone against my advice on variable naming. That's Crockford for you. ;-) ]

Comment: I keep looking at it and I keep thinking that I better use `array_key_exists($key,$object);` instead of complicating it to objects, all it does it looks for duplicate keys lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for properties:

```
property_exists($class_instance, 'YourProperty');
```

for methods:

```
method_exists($class_instance, 'YourMethod');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: Be aware that prior to php 5.3 `property_exists` will return false on `protected` and `private` properties.

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It does not seem correct. hasOwnProperty returns false for inherited properties, property_exists returns true.

Comment: As @Alex already said, this answer is wrong because it takes inherited properties into account, which is **not the case** of Javascript's `hasOwnProperty()`. That's what "own" stands for...

Answer (score 5):

Or using reflection (See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
<?php
$obj = (object)array('test' => 1);
$key = 'test';

$refObj = new ReflectionObject($obj);
var_dump($refObj->hasProperty($key));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach using **reflection**. http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

Let's say I have this configuration:

```
class A
{
    protected static $name = 'blabla';
}

class B extends A
{
    //
}

class C extends A
{
    protected static $name = null;
}

class D extends A
{
    protected static $name = '324';
}
```

I define this function in my base class:

```
class A
{
    // ...

    public static function hasOwnProperty($property_name)
    {
        $property = (new \ReflectionClass(static::class))->getProperty($property_name);
        return $property->class === static::class;
    }
}
```

Then I can call it from the base class itself and any child class:

```
>>> A::hasOwnProperty('name');
=> true

>>> B::hasOwnProperty('name');
=> false

>>> C::hasOwnProperty('name');
=> true

>>> D::hasOwnProperty('name');
=> true
```

Notice that it returns `true` even if the value is `null`, which is the expected behaviour I think. That seems to take the best of both `isset()` and `property_exists()`.

Keep in mind that reflection is a performance-hitting process though.